# The practice of raising prices to keep undesirables out

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word meaning the practice of raising prices to keep certain "undesirable" people out? A couple examples:

1. A bar sells beer for $4/pint. The price is too cheap, and a certain class of peeps start showing up. Owners of the establishment want them out, so they raise prices to $7/pint, which effectively forces them out.
2. A town raises taxes and rental prices to make them inaccessible to certain people, despite equal opportunity laws. This keeps makes housing in certain neighborhoods inaccessible to certain people.

(I realize that this is a touchy subject. I've been told that this is quite illegal in the USA; but speeding is illegal too... and it happens all the time. I didn't say I agree with it, I'm just looking for a word to describe it.)

I've been searching and asking around for weeks but can't find this word. Some suggestions so far:

- *paywalling* is more for web-based content
- *price fixing* fits better with a group of businesses agreeing on a bottom-line price
- *vigorish* means a tax paid to a casino... similar, but not a great fit.
- *segregation* is not quite on target

What is the name of this practice? Ty.

Comment: There is an idiom  to *price (someone) out of the market.* "To make the price of something to high for (someone)"  m-w

Comment: @DjinTonic ty That's definitely the best so far. They're being ``priced out`` of the market.

Comment: *[Premium pricing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premium_pricing)* is related, but seems to primarily refer to having high prices to give an impression of being a high quality, luxury or premium product, rather than specifically to keep people out.

Comment: The phrase "keeping out the riff raff" is sometimes used in this context. The admission charge is very high, but it does keep out the riff raff. The high price of the beer helps to keep out the riff raff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**price out / price out of the market**

> *Transitive*. **to price out of the market**: to eliminate (oneself or
> another) from effective commercial competition through prohibitive
> prices; to charge a prohibitive price for (goods or services) or to
> (the customer). Also to **price out** (frequently in passive): to
> charge a prohibitive price to (a potential customer); to prevent (a
> person) from buying something because of prohibitive prices;
> similarly **to price (someone) out of (something).** OED

> **price (someone) out of the market** (idiom)
>
> To make the price of something too high for (someone)
>
> *The high rents are pricing some people out of the market.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/price%20out%20of%20the%20market)

---

> Although the cheapest three boroughs in 1995 were still the cheapest
> in 2007, these boroughs had among the highest rates of house price
> inflation in London in 1995-2007, which has intensified problems of
> affordability for those attempting to buy, many of whom are
> effectively **priced out** of ownership and into private renting or
> social housing which have both grown dramatically. [T. Butler and C.
> Hamnet;
> *Ethnicity, Class and Aspiration*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ethnicity_Class_and_Aspiration/AuBU7vb1XwQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=they%20were%20effectively%20priced%20out&pg=PA75&printsec=frontcover)

> In ***Priced Out***, Reinhardt offers an engaging and enlightening account
> of today’s U.S. health care system, explaining why it costs so much
> more and delivers so much less than the systems of every other
> advanced country, why this situation is morally indefensible, and how
> we might improve it. [Blurb](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691192178/priced-out) for Uwe E. Reinhardt; ***Priced Out**: The Economic and Ethical
> Costs of American Health Care*

> Like so many longtime residents, Ken agreed that the middle class has
> been **priced out** of Stuyvesant Town: The pricing structure, of
> course, has all changed since when we moved in. [R. A. Woldoff et al.;
> ***Priced Out**: Stuyvesant Town and the Loss of Middle-Class Neighborhoods*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Priced_Out/IALMCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=priced%20out&pg=PA62&printsec=frontcover)

> Mr. TUGGLE. I think it will be about the same and upward, because
> again certain qualities are simply **priced out of the market**,
> particularly lower quality leaf, and that practice means we are going
> to **price** your fourth, fifth, and sixth grade tobacco **out of the word
> market.** The problem to me was rather simple. [US Congress;
> *Flue-Cured Tobacco Price Support Program for 1979 Marketing Year*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Flue_cured_Tobacco_Price_Support_Program/w0tJAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=priced%20out%20of%20the%20market&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover).